# const references to temporary objects

Tags: c++, c++11

In article ["Move semantics and rvalue references in C++11"](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) by Alex Allain, I read:

> Notice, by the way, that holding on to a `const` reference to a
>   temporary object ensures that the temporary object isn't immediately
>   destructed. This is a nice guarantee of `C++`, but it is still a
>   temporary object, so you don't want to modify it.

Of course I know that a const reference is not, nor behaves like, a `shared_ptr` (which one would hope, reading "holding on `[...]` the temporary object isn't immediately destructed"), but I wasn't able to find any more reference.
So the question is: How is this addressed in the standard?

Comment: What do you mean "how is this addressed"? Are you asking what C++ does with temporaries bound to ref-to-non-`const`? Or what?

Comment: The "duplicate" doesn't mention extending the temporary's lifetime by binding to a reference; it only covers the normal lifetime of a temporary. See C++11 12.2/5 for details, but the summary is just what the article says: if a temporary is used directly to initialise a reference (which must be `const`), then its lifetime is extended to match that of the reference.